# Question : In the graph there are 100 vertices and 800 edges. Can this graph have all vertices with degree 16?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Question : In the graph there are 100 vertices and 800 edges. Can this graph have all vertices with degree 16?

Solution : This kind of graph exists. For example, consider all vertices in a circle. Let's connect each vertex with the 8th one standing in a row to the right of it and with the 8th one standing in a row to the left of it.

That's all was the solution. I didn't understand it. Please help me.

Comment: The given solution makes it clear that every vertex has degree 16.  Another way of thinking of this solution:  imagine all of the vertices on a circle.  Choose a vertex, say $v_0$, and construct edges which join $v_0$ to the $8$ vertices counterclockwise of $v_0$.  Let $v_1$ be the vertex next counterclockwise from $v_0$.  Construct edges which join $v_1$ to the next $8$ vertices counterclockwise.  Continue in this manner around the circle.  At each vertex, you will construct $8$ edges, so there are $800$ edges, total.

Comment: On the other hand, when the process completes, each vertex will be joined to the $8$ vertices counterclockwise of itself (by explicit construction), and will be joined to the $8$ vertices clockwise of itself (when we construct the $8$ edges "emanating" from each of those vertices).  Hence every vertex has degree $16$.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Your explanation is clear. The given one, much less so.

Comment: Well, the given explanation seems wrong, or perhaps is a poor translation?  If you replace “the 8th one standing in a row” (??) with “the 8 vertices”, it becomes clear and correct.

Comment: wikipedia gives the same graph, a circulant graph: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_graph#existence. Although when $n$ is even and $n/2>=k$ you can also build one by taking disjoint matchings of $K_{n/2,n/2}$

Comment: There's lots of options; one very concise one is take five disjoint copies of $K_{4,4,4,4,4}$.